# Plotting latitude / longitude from Excel spreadsheet using Cartopy

Tags: python, pandas, mapping, gis, cartopy

Trying to plot a survey transect on a map using Cartopy, a library seriously lacking in online information compared to others.
My lat/long data is in two seperate columns of an Excel spreadsheet.

I have managed to build a basemap, and my script for that is as follows:

```
import cartopy.feature as cf

map = plt.figure(figsize=(15,15))
ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.EuroPP())
ax.coastlines(resolution='10m')

ax.add_feature(cf.LAND)
ax.add_feature(cf.OCEAN)
ax.add_feature(cf.COASTLINE)
ax.add_feature(cf.BORDERS, linestyle=':')
ax.add_feature(cf.LAKES, alpha=0.5)
ax.add_feature(cf.RIVERS)

ax.stock_img()
```

Producing the following figure [image: figure]

I have also read in the data from Excel columns labeled 'latitude' (column 'L') and 'longitude' (column 'M') using pandas, from the following spreadsheet:
https://liveplymouthac-my.sharepoint.com/:x:/g/personal/rhodri_irranca-davies_postgrad_plymouth_ac_uk/EYGoEUAO8tBLkdT0r4dwDdsBAijsVChsLCec-DxaYo2Tew?e=rs9cBc

This was done using the following code:

```
file = r'C:\Users\Laptop\Documents\Python\Thesis\t2_GeoData.xlsx'
df_lat = pd.read_excel(file, index_col=None, na_values=['NA'], usecols = 'L')
df_lon = pd.read_excel(file, index_col=None, na_values=['NA'], usecols = 'M')
```

Was pandas the right option? If so, how do I now incorporate the two dataframes created ('df_lat' and 'df_lon') and plot them as transects using cartopy?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean exactly as plot them as transects, but you can plot lon/lat lines in CartoPy with:

```
ax.plot(df_lon, df_lat, linestyle='-', color='orange', transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())
```

Comment: Sorry @DopplerShift speaking as an biologist/ecologist! But yes essentially trying to plot the lat/long coords. This has worked well thank you, however it has zoomed right in on the transect, how would I control the magnification and zoom back out?

Comment: You want to use `ax.set_extent()` to set the bounds of the plot. It might be good to look through the examples here: https://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/latest/gallery/index.html